# Using Perl's ExtUtils::MakeMaker, how can I compile an executable using the same settings as my XS module?

Tags: c, perl, perl-xs, makemaker

Given a Perl XS module using a C library, assume there is a Makefile.PL that is set up correctly so that all header and library locations, compiler and linker flags etc work correctly.

Now, let's say I want to include a small C program with said XS module that uses the same underlying C library. What is the correct, platform independent way to specify the target executable so that it gets built with the same settings and flags?

If I do the following

```
sub MY::postamble {
    return <<FRAG;
target$Config{exe_ext}: target$Config{obj_ext}

target$Config{obj_ext}: target.c

FRAG
}
```

I don't get those include locations, lists of libraries etc I set up in the arguments to `WriteMakefile`. If I start writing rules manually, I have to account for at least `make`, `dmake`, and `nmake`. I can't figure out a straightforward way to specify libraries to link against if use [ExtUtils::CBuilder](https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils%3a%3aCBuilder).

I must be missing something. I would appreciate it if you can point it out.

Answer (score 2):

**EU::MM does not know how to create executable**. If you need to do this, you will need to take into account various compiler toolchains. I've done this at least [once](https://metacpan.org/source/LEONT/App-a2p-1.007/Makefile.PL#L77), but I don't claim it's completely portable (just portable enough).

A long term solution would be a proper compilation framework, I've been working on that but it's fairly non-trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [Dist::Zilla](https://metacpan.org/release/Dist-Zilla). I use it because I can never remember how to do this either. With a fairly small and boilerplaty `dist.ini` file to tell it which plugins to use, it'll generate the all the right building systems for you, including the whole of the necessary `Makefile.PL`. Think of it it as a makefile-maker-maker. I use it for one of my smaller and more broken C-based CPAN modules: https://github.com/morungos/p5-Algorithm-Diff-Fast, which doesn't work especially well as module but has a decent build. The magic needed is in the `inc/DiffMakeMaker.pm`.

However, the short answer is to look at the extra settings this component drops into `Makefile.PL`:

```
LIBS => [''],
INC => '-I.',
OBJECT => '$(O_FILES)', # link all the C files too
```

Just adding these options into your `Makefile.PL` should get it to build a `Makefile` that handles C as well as XS, and links them together for the Perl.

Because, although EU::MM doesn't know how to create an executable, most of what it does it to make a Makefile. And that's more than happy to make what's needed to glue the C and Perl together properly.