# ExtUtils::MakeMaker compile helper utility

Tags: perl, makemaker

Can I persuade EU::MM to compile a helper utility without looking for XS to build?

For example, given the following:

```
  Makefile.PL
  helper.c
  example.pl
  lib/App/Example.pm
```

... a *make* on the generated Makefile tries to work with a dynamic library:

```
$:- cat Makefile.PL
use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;
WriteMakefile(
  NAME              => 'App::Example',
  VERSION_FROM      => 'lib/App/Example.pm', # finds $VERSION
);
$:- perl Makefile.PL 
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for App::Example
$:- make
cp lib/App/Example.pm blib/lib/App/Example.pm
AutoSplitting blib/lib/App/Example.pm (blib/lib/auto/App/Example)
Running Mkbootstrap for App::Example ()
chmod 644 Example.bs
rm -f blib/arch/auto/App/Example/Example.so
gcc  -shared .... Example.o  -o blib/arch/auto/App/Example/Example.so   \
        \

gcc: Example.o: No such file or directory
gcc: no input files
make: *** [blib/arch/auto/App/Example/Example.so] Error 1
```

What I'd ultimately like is to have *helper* built and installed under `/usr/bin`, *example.pl* under `/usr/sbin`, and App::Example under `$Config{vendorlib}`.  However, I need the pure perl modules "built" correctly first.  Playing with C and EXE_FILES directives didn't change this behavior.

Comment: I believe this is related to [Using Perl's ExtUtils::MakeMaker, how can I compile an executable using the same settings as my XS module?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23161910/100754). Note, this is not a vote to close as duplicate, just pointing out what I believe is a related question.